# Cannot get an advanced stats from IEX Cloud API

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

Cannot get the advanced-stats from IEX Cloud. Could you please help me to resolve this tackle? Just to clarify, it works for stats, quotes etc.

```py
import requests

symbol = 'AAPL'
IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN = 'sk_80e742117fc345ea92728199633d8f33'
base_url = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable'

url_adv_stats = f'{base_url}/stock/{symbol}/advanced-stats?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'

response_adv_stats = requests.get(url_adv_stats)
response_adv_stats.json()
```

The error :

```
Error file:JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to decode, as you ran out of quota. Please check `r.status_code` and also `r.text`, as shown below. The status code should be `2XX`. A comprehensive list of status codes can be found [here](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#status).

```
import requests

symbol = 'AAPL'
IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN = 'sk_80e742117fc345ea92728199633d8f33'

base_url = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable'
url_adv_stats = f'{base_url}/stock/{symbol}/advanced-stats?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'
r = requests.get(url_adv_stats)

print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)

json = r.json()
print(json)
```

**Output:**

```
The requested data is not available to free tier accounts. Please upgrade for access to this data.
402
...
```

Comment: Yes, It was caused by free tier account plan so it needs to be upgraded properly :) Sry for that :)